# $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=2$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} y_n=-2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ be two sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=2$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} y_n=-2$. Then:

1. $x_n\geq y_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.
2. $x_n^2\geq y_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.
3. There exist $m\in \mathbb N$ such that $|{x_n}|\leq y_n^2$ for all $n>m$.
4. There exist $m\in \mathbb N$ such that $|{x_n}|=| y_n|$ for all $n>m$.

So this was a Multiple choice (Single correct) question. $1$ is false because if we assume the constant sequences then equality does not hold, couldn't construct a counter for $2$, rather $3$ is the only correct answer (no idea why?). If we have $-y_n^2\leq x_n\leq y_n^2$, won't that claim $3$ to be wrong? Tried $x_n=\frac{1+2^{n+1}}{1+2^n}$ (this converges to 2) and keeping $y_n=-2$ ($4$ is completely out of the game since such $m$ need not exist). Any help? Thanks.

Comment: For $(2)$ take $x = 2,2,2,2,\ldots$ and $y= 5,-2,-2,-2,\ldots$ as a counterexample.

Comment: For 3.: If $y_n\to-2$ then $y_n^2\to4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is false, for the reason that you have mentioned.
2. It is false too. Take *any* number $a$ greater than $4$ and let $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be the constant sequence $2$ and $(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be the sequence $a,-2,-2,-2,\ldots$
3. It is true, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n|=2$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n^{\,2}=4$.
4. It is false. Take, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $x_n=2$ and $y_n=-2+\frac1n$.